# Opengpg.js Encrypt/Decrypyt example

Tags: javascript, openpgp.js

I'm trying to get a simple test of opengpg.js working.

I'm getting the following output:

```
Encrypted Message[object Object]
```

What in this code causes this error?

```
var openpgp = require('openpgp');

var options = {
    numBits: 1024,
    userId: 'user@localhost',
    passphrase: 'password'
};

openpgp.generateKeyPair(options).then(function(keypair) {

    var privkey = keypair.privateKeyArmored;
    var pubkey = keypair.publicKeyArmored;

    console.log("Pub key" + pubkey + "\n\n");

    var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey);
    var pgpMessage = openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys,"Hello");

    console.log("Encrypted Message" + pgpMessage + "\n\n");

    }).catch(function(error) {
    // failure
    console.log("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: "What in this code causes this error?"  *What error*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on the assumption that by "error" you mean 
"unexpected output".

`openpgp.encryptMessage` returns a [*promise*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not the encrypted text.  See the [opengpg.js documentation](http://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/module-openpgp.html).

To get the value from the promise, it's the same as any other promise:

```
openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys,"Hello").then(function(pgpMessage) {
    // success
    console.log("Encrypted Message" + pgpMessage + "\n\n");
}).catch(function(error) {
    // failure
});
```

Comment: This does not work any more. The method has been renamed.

Comment: @codebird456 Is [this](https://openpgpjs.org/openpgpjs/doc/module-openpgp.html#.encrypt) the updated method you're referring to?  I will update my answer.  Looks like they also altered the parameters and the return type, so I'd like to confirm this is the correct method.

Comment: yes it is. I struggle to get it correctly as a lot has changed. It seems like an options object should be created the like:  var options2 = {
          message: openpgp.message.fromText('hallooo'), // input as Message object
          publicKeys: publicKey,
          // publicKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(publicKeyAliceArmored).keys,

          // passwords: ['secret stuff'],                                             // multiple passwords possible
          armor: true                                                             // don't ASCII armor (for Uint8Array output)
      };